# Unity : To rotate 3d Object to align 2D isometric field

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

I want to rotate a car to align isometric field like above picture.

but i have any idea about that.

Do you have a some of idea to solve it?

Comment: Try rotating the X & Y or Y & Z or X & Z etc. axis 30 degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most quasi-isometric games use this:

```
x = 30, y = 45 degrees rotation
```

Of course, you might need to flip the values between axis or make one negative to align with your world.

Generally, I would recommend to choose either approach: Do it in 3d and position the orthographic camera so that it looks isometric/dimetric, however you want to. Or just stick with 2d isometric sprites all together. You might run into many more problems otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I used function this for rotation object in Unity 3D by AWSD key. You can refer.

```
void Update () {
        float x = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 150.0f;
        float z = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 3.0f;

        transform.Rotate (0, x, 0);
        transform.Translate (0, 0, z);
}
```

Comment: No. i want to the formular that getting the value to proper that.